# How to stop keyboard from getting dismissed?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, keyboard

I am using `textformfield` in flutter. Whenever user types something I give him suggestion. When user taps on suggestion, keyboard is dismissed automatically. I want to stop keyboard from getting dismissed. How to do it? I want user to add suggestion continuously.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `FocusNode` [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html):

> FocusNodes are ChangeNotifiers, so a listener can be registered to receive a notification when the focus changes.

```
 final _focusNode = FocusNode();
```

So you can `addListener` to it to track changes that happens to it when you assign that `FocusNode` to the `TextFormField`:

```
TextFormField(
 focusNode: _focusNode,
 // ...
 ),
```

You can add the listener, then check if it has focus, which means that you're checking if the `TextFormField` field is focused, which also means that if the keyboard is shown:

```
_focusNode.addListener(() {
  if(!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
  }
});
```

by this, it will remain the `TextFormField` focused, when you're done with it, you can call the `removeListener()`.

Comment: This is working. But, how can I detect when user clicks anywhere except suggestion so that I can call remove listener.

Comment: it's up to you and your app I guess, but consider wrapping the whole Scaffold with a GestureDetector that will remove that listener, so it will be executed only if you click elssewhere

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this on

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

Or  final FocusNode textFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();

```
TextFormField(
             focusNode: textFieldFocusNode,
              onTap: () async {
               textFieldFocusNode.requestFocus();
                 },
)
```

Comment: Go to this for better understanding https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/focus

Comment: This is used to dismiss keyboard. I want to have keyboard all the time.

Comment: final FocusNode textFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();
TextFormField(
focusNode: textFieldFocusNode,  
onTap: () async {
  textFieldFocusNode.requestFocus();
  },

)

Answer (score 0):

Give FocusNode to Textformfield and focus that particular node on tapping of suggestion like this:

```
//Assign this inputNode to TextFormField
FocusNode inputNode = FocusNode();

//Somewhere on TextFormField
TextFormField(
  focusNode:inputNode
)

// to open keyboard call this function;
void openKeyboard(){
   FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(inputNode)
}
```

Comment: This is not working, I have tried this.